# Enemy does not look in upward direction when the player is at height

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enemy not looking at the player standing at height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRjNm.png)  my enemy does not look in the upward direction while shooting when the player is standing at the height i used these two methods but none of them making the enemy look towards the player when the player is at some height , im also adding the picture to make it clear

First method :

```
                transform.LookAt (ThePlayer.transform.position);
```

Seond method:

```
   Vector3 direction = ThePlayer.transform.position - transform.position;
        direction.y = 0;
    if (direction.x != 0 && direction.z != 0) {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation 
      (direction), 1.5f * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
```

Comment: And which `transform` is that that you're making look at the player? Dollars to doughnuts it's not the enemy's *head.*

Comment: @Draco18s FPScontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah on Draco18s's post, you should try moving the enemy's head with Tranform.LookAt(myplayer.trasform.position) however note that the enemy will look at the player's pivot point, so if the player's pivot point is at their feet, that is where the enemy will look.
Best of luck.